# How to use the result of an ajax request in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a query which returns 2 rows. Here is my PHP code:

```
$arr = array();

$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM mytable WHERE id <= 2");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
/*Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [id] => 1
              [name] => pear
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [id] => 2
              [name] => watermelon
          )

  ) */

$arr["output"] = $result;

header('Content-Type: application/json');   
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```

And here is my JS code:

```
success: function(arr) {
    $(".myclass").html(arr.output.0.name);
}
```

And it throws this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

When I remove `.0.name`, it throws this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Anyway, how can I show the result of a ajax request when there is multiple rows selected?

All I want to make is a HTML table of the result like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>pear</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>watermelon</td>
</tr>
```

And then push it into `$('.myclass')` element.

Comment: `arr.output.0.name` is a syntax error because `0` is a number, but you're trying to access a property from it. Access the array like `arr.output[0].name`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` to parse the string (`data`) back into an array.

```
success: function(data) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(data);
    $(".myclass").text(arr.output[0].name);
}
```

And use subscripts for arrays. And if you want to set the text of the `.myclass` as mentioned in a comment use `.text` instead of `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is returned as json, you need to access the array of objects, change

```
$(".myclass").html(arr.output.0.name);
```

to

```
$(".myclass").text(arr.output[0].name);
```